# Mysql insert and select id of inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am inserting 1 row in mysql table that has auto_increment id value and want to get id of that row.
Do you know some construction like

```
{
 INSERT INTO some_table (`name`) VALUES ('test name')
 ON SUCCESS RETURN id
}
```

Table structure:

```
id: int not null auto_increment Primary key
name: Varchar (20)
```

I read about LAST_INSERT_ID, but if my script was called simultaneously, there is a change of 2 different inserts and LAST_INSERT_ID can return wrong value.

I am using php and prepared statements that does not allow several commit and/or rollback.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO some_table (`name`) VALUES ('test name')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$last_id =  mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Good solution. For future references, $con->insert_id;

Comment: Keep in mind, that this extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. You should use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong assumptions about multiuser use of PHP PDO. Last insert ID is stored in PDO object created upon connection. So this "last insert ID" value is stored per connection. This way simultaneous calls will not interfere with each other.

Here's [manual reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Answer (score 1):

First do the insert

```
INSERT INTO some_table (`name`) VALUES ('test name');
```

Then immediately after do

```
SELECT id FROM some_table WHERE name = 'test name';
```

And make sure you capture the output of latter one (this may vary depending on how you connect to your DB).

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you could do this right after the insert:

```
SELECT id FROM some_table WHERE name = 'test name' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

This way you can avoid getting an earlier input with the same name.

Comment: I plan to do exactly the same, but as name can be non unique, so think to add 'createdtime' datatime, filed with NOW() value and add orderby createdtime to get latest data.